# Dojo disable all input fields in div container

Tags: input, dojo

Is there any way to disable all input fields in an div container with dojo?

Something like:

```
dijit.byId('main').disable -> Input
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure there is. Open up this [form test page](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.3.1/dojo-release-1.3.1/dijit/tests/form/test_CheckBox.html) for example, launch FireBug and execute in the console:

```
var container = dojo.query('div')[13];
console.log(container);
dojo.query('input', container).forEach(
  function(inputElem){
    console.log(inputElem);
    inputElem.disabled = 'disabled';
  }
)
```

Notes:

- On that test page form elements are actually dijit form widgets, but in this sample I'm treating them as if they were normal input tags
- The second dojo.query selects all input elements within the `container` element. If the container had some unique id, you could simplify the sample by having only one dojo.query: `dojo.query('#containerId input').forEach( ...`
- forEach loops through all found input elements and applies the given function on them.

**Update:** There's also a shortcut for setting an attribute value using [NodeList](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/NodeList)'s `attr` function instead of `forEach`. [attr](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/attr) takes first the attribute name and then the value or an object with name/value pairs:

```
var container = dojo.query('div')[13];
dojo.query('input', container).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 11):

That's how I do it:

```
dojo.query("input, button, textarea, select", container).attr("disabled", true);
```

This one-liner disables all form elements in the given container.

Answer (score 6):

Something else to keep in mind is the difference between A Dijit and a regular DomNode. If you want all Dijit's within a DomNode, you can convert them from Nodes -> Dijit refs with query no problem:

```
// find all widget-dom-nodes in a div, convert them to dijit reference:
var widgets = dojo.query("[widgetId]", someDiv).map(dijit.byNode);
// now iterate over that array making each disabled in dijit-land:
dojo.forEach(widgets, function(w){ w.attr("disabled", "disabled"); }
```

It really just depends on if your inputs are regular Dom input tags or have been converted into the rich Dijit templates (which all do have a regular input within them, just controlled by the widget reference instead)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
var widgets;

require(["dijit/registry", "dojo/dom"], function(registry, dom){
    widgets = registry.findWidgets(dom.byId(domId));
});

require(["dojo/_base/array"], function(array){
    array.forEach(widgets, function(widget, index) {
        widget.set("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

Method findWidgets is essential to get all widgets underneath a specific DOM.